# How to redirect a iframe hosted in different domain from other users other than called from owner different domains

Tags: jquery, html, redirect

We have a html page which are planning to use using iframe, but we don't wan't others using our page as an iframe.But we host our page that will be iframed in different domain.

How can i restrict in such a way only our domains get that page in iframe whereas other domains can't?

I am looking for some javascript or jquery solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `window.parent.location` for your domain name,
If it's not there redirect the browser, something like:

```
if(window.parent.location.indexOf("myDomain") == 0)
     good;
else
     window.parent.location = "http://myDomain";
```